# Show that $\sum_{cyc} J(x,J(y,z))=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let $x,y,z$ be functions of $(u,v)$ and $J$ be the Jacobian matrix.
>
> Show that $\sum_{cyc} J(x,J(y,z))=0$.

I expanded the thing and realized that the first term in the sum is $x_u(J(y,z_v)+J(y_v,z))-x_v (J(y,z_u)+J(y_u,z))$, but I don't know how to carry on then. Furthermore, I suspect that this has something to do with the [jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity), but I don't know are they related.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand notation (what is the Jacoby matrix of 2 functions?).
In any case, if

$$J(x,y):=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} $$

and $x=x(u,v)$, $y=y(u,v)$, then the statement is the Jacobi identity for the Poisson bracket of functions on $\mathbb R^2$, i.e.

$$J(x,y):=\{x,y\}. $$

Comment: You're right about the notation.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid poisson bracket?

Comment: If notation is correct, then $J(x,y)$ is the Poisson bracket of $x$ and $y$. It is commonly denoted by $J(x,y):=\{x,y\}$. I edit my answer.